# Trying to create a method that clears all the nodes in a linked list in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that clears all the nodes in a LinkedList; I was able to come up with this

I have tried to loop through the linked list and get to the last valid node in the linked list using a while loop. Then I tried to assign top to next.getLink() which will be null. Is this correct ?

```
public void clear() {
    TileNode next = top;
    while (next != null) {
        next = next.getLink();
    }
    top = next.getLink();
}
```

My instructor says that there is an easier way to do it so I am wondering what it could be ? Could we assign top = null directly ?

Comment: (removed python tag as the question has nothing to do with python).

Comment: What does clearing mean? You are just iterating over nodes of the list and thats it. You mean deleting data in nodes? Or removing nodes itself (could be achieved by setting top to null and let garbage collector delete unused objects). Moreover `top = next.getLink();` will cause NPE in current implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clear the content of all nodes then simple iterate one by one all nodes and set it data to null/0 or if you want delete all nodes then you set it header to null. In java grabge collector remove all unused objects.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are asking about singly linked list. You can set the head of the linked list to `null`. Garbage collection will take care of removing the rest since once head is set to null, nothing is pointing to rest of the nodes.